# Regex to find files with certain number of underscores

Tags: regex

I have two files:

```
AAAAA_AAAA_BBBBBBBB_SSSSSS
AAAAA_BBBBBBBB_SSSSSS
```

I want only the file with two underscores be shown.

I used:

```
ls -1 ^?*_?*_?*$
```

I got:

```
ls: ?*_?*_?*$: No such file or directory
```

Why?  And what can be a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've mixed up *shell globs* and *regular expression syntax* - and come up with something that's not valid in either.

If you want to use a regex based tool, try `find` e.g.

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -regex '^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$'
```

Comment: Thanks. ls | grep  '^[^_]*_[^_]*_[^_]*$' also works. Why just ls cannot take regex?

Comment: @JosefKlimuk the `ls` command itself doesn't interpret the pattern - that's done by the shell (and it uses a much simpler [glob syntax](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) )